# How to change the labels of samples in CCA plot

Tags: r

By using the `vegan` package, I drew a `CCA` plot. I have add the first column in the `envi` file as the names of samples. However,the samples in the plot were labeled as the default,such as `row1,row2,....`. I want to change the lables of samples to the specific ones as listed in my tables,such as `Jan.S1,Jan.S2,.....`. How should I change the labels? Besides,how to change the location of these labels in order to avoid the overlapping with dots?

Here, I attached my codes as follows:

```
speciesdata=read.csv("species.csv", header=T, sep=",") 
envdata= read.csv("envi.csv", header=T, sep=",")
Miseq.cca=cca(speciesdata ~ TN + TP + NH4  + pH + Zn + Pb + Cd + Ni + Cr, data = envdata)
Miseq.cca
plot(Miseq.cca,display=c("si","bp"),scaling=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the argument `row.names=1`. This will make R assume that the first column of the csv sheet is the sample name, and not data.

Ex: 
1) Put "Jan.S1, Jan.S2,....." on the first column of your species.csv file.

2) Use `speciesdata=read.csv("species.csv", header=T, sep=",",row.names=1)` on R script.